# Bash scripting: redirect output of slow commands to file

Tags: bash, output, buffer

I'm running the below script from an udev rule so that when I Start a printer, it looks for the remaining ink in the cartridges and sens an email with these info. Overall, it Works well, except the escputil command that is outputting its data quite slowly. Therefore, my intermediate "out" file is empty and the notification email is also empty.

I tried stdbuf to fix it, standard redirection or tee, none helped.
Any idea? Thanks in advance,

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir /var/lock/epson || exit 1
now=`date +%s`
limit=$((now - 1800))

if [ -f /tmp/epson.ink ] && [ `cat /tmp/epson.ink` -ge $limit ]; then
    rmdir /var/lock/epson && exit 0
fi
sleep 6

stdbuf -oL -eL escputil --quiet --ink-level --raw-device /dev/usb/lp0 2>/dev/null | tee /tmp/epson.out
cat /tmp/epson.out | tail -5 | mail -s "Epson printer ink level" email@example.com
echo "$now" > /tmp/epson.ink

rmdir /var/lock/epson
exit 0
```

Comment: so `escputil` terminates before the `out` file is written?

Comment: It shouldn't matter how slowly the command runs. If it writes to `stdout` the pipe will catch it and write it to the file before the command returns. Are you sure `escputil` isn't writing to `stderr` instead or something?

Comment: No because if I run this command on the shell, I got the output. If it was printing to stderr, with the redirection to /dev/null, I wouldn't see any output.

Comment: What happens when you run the command manually exactly as the script does. i.e. with the redirection and the tee?

Comment: It works as expected; I have the output in the console and in the file.

Comment: it's really just in the environment used with this script, triggered by udev, where it's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *BUGS* section in the manpage `escputil(1)` mentions that the printer may not return a result immediately when starting up.

I would suggest repeating the command and check for the output after each try. In this example, I assume that `/tmp/epson.out` does not exist or is empty when the script starts (otherwise add `rm -rf` at the beginning):

```
# as long as the file does not exist or is empty:
while ! [ -e /tmp/epson.out ] || [ $( wc -m < /tmp/epson.out ) -le 0 ]
do 
  escputil --quiet --ink-level --raw-device /dev/usb/lp0 2>/dev/null | tee /tmp/epson.out
  sleep 5
done
```

I cannot test it here, but I do not think `stdbuf` will be useful to you.

Comment: That worked indeed, multiple rune of the escputil and I got the expected email :) Thanks for the tip!